# Change value after check element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, redux

I want to display elements from my db and after the click, I want to change the value (accept users post). Generally, this code works but if I click on an element it displays me an error that props.actions is not a function. At this time I want to update the accept value into my db and update this element in the react app (but at this time this second think is not important). So how can I update this value? Backend I make in Laravel.

form

```
    import React from  'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import actions from '../actions'


const WomenForm = (props) => {
    const womenInput = React.createRef();

    const addWoman = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        props.add(womenInput.current.value);
        womenInput.current.value = '';
    }

    return <form onSubmit={addWoman}>
        <input ref={womenInput} />
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    add: woman => dispatch(actions.add(woman))
})

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(WomenForm);
```

women

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {getAllWomen, acceptWomen} from '../operations'
import actions from '../actions'


const WomenContainer = ({ women, getAllWomen }) => {
    useEffect(() => { getAllWomen() }, [])

    const acceptWoman = (props) => {
        props.accept();
      }

    return <ul>
        {women.map(woman => <li onClick={acceptWoman}>{woman}</li>)}
    </ul>
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    title: state.women.title,
    women: state.women.list
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    getAllWomen: () => dispatch(getAllWomen()),
    acceptWomen: () => dispatch(acceptWomen()),
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(WomenContainer);
```

actions

```
const add = woman => ({type: 'ADD_WOMEN', item: woman });
const reset = () => ({type: 'RESET_WOMEN'});
const accept = () => ({type: 'ACCEPT_WOMAN', item: 1});


export default {
    add,
    reset,
    accept
}
```

operations

```
import actions from './actions'

const fetchWomen = async() => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/test/movies', { methd: 'GET' })
    const json = await response.json()

    return JSON
}

export const getAllWomen = () =>
  async (dispatch) => {
    const women = await fetchWomen()
    women.map(woman => dispatch(actions.add(woman.title)))
  }
const acceptFetchWomen = async() => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/test/movie/1', { methd: 'GET' })
    const json = await response.json()

    return JSON
}

export const acceptWomen = () =>
  async (dispatch) => {
    const women = await acceptFetchWomen()
    women.map(woman => dispatch(actions.accept(woman.id)))
  }
```

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is it an oversight that `const accept = () => ({type: 'ACCEPT_WOMAN', item: 1});` does not accept a parameter?
I'm asking because you call it with one:
`women.map(woman => dispatch(actions.accept(woman.id)))`

If that it is not the problem it might help to get the full error from your console and/or the reducers.

Comment: Yes, becouse I used 1 value to test but finally it will be id of element.